# Add count next to each aggregated value

Tags: python, django

I currently aggregate a query to get a unique list of strings used in my endpoint. As of now, the fetched data looks like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        "Beige",
        "Grey",
        ...
    ]
}
```

However, I'm attempting to do something like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            name: "Beige",
            count: 7
        },
        {
            name: "Grey",
            count: 3
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Where count is the amount of times the value occurs in the datbase.

Currently, my viewset is structured like this:

```
class ProductFiltersByCategory(APIView):
    """
    This viewset takes the category parameter from the url and returns related product filters
    """

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Gets parameter in urls and aggregated filtered result
        """
        category = self.kwargs['category']

        aggregated_result = Product.objects.filter(
                category__parent__name__iexact=category,
                status='available'
            ).distinct().aggregate(data=ArrayAgg('colors__name', distinct=True))
        
        return Response(aggregated_result)
```

How do i go about making the key-value pair structure i want, as well as do the count for each "color"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate the `Count` of each category and group by that category using `.values()`. Since your relations involve a many-to-many field, you probably just want to do the query on the Color model rather than the Product model.

```
Color.objects.filter(
    product__category__parent__name__iexact=category,
    product__status='available'
).values('name', 'product').annotate(
    colors_count=Count('product', distinct=True)
).values_list('name', 'colors_count')
```

Comment: Thank you! The count, however, is wrong, probably because its a ManyToMany field and the colors occur multiple times in the table. For example, on of the colors count 7, but there are only three products in the database, of which all have white as a registered color. Doing `distinct=True` on the Count method doesnt work either, as it only shows the count of 1 on each instance. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try putting a distinct after the first values clause, or query on the Color model instead of the Product model. I've updated the answer. I know I always spend a little extra time on these problems. You may also want to checkout the Django documentation on aggregation.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: Seems like filtering on the Color model is the easiest. I've marked your answer correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from random import choices
from collections import Counter
from pprint import pprint

colours = ['White', 'Yellow', 'Blue', 'Red', 'Green', 'Black', 'Brown', 'Azure', 'Ivory', 'Teal', 'Silver', 'Purple', 'Navy blue', 'Pea green', 'Gray',
           'Orange', 'Maroon', 'Charcoal', 'Aquamarine', 'Coral', 'Fuchsia', 'Wheat', 'Lime', 'Crimson', 'Khaki', 'Hot pink', 'Magenta', 'Olden', 'Plum', 'Olive', 'Cyan']

data = {"data": choices(colours, k=10)}
pprint(data)
newData = {"data": [{"name": k, "count": v} for k,v in Counter(data["data"]).items()]}
pprint(newData)
```

Sample Output:

```
{'data': ['Coral',
          'Ivory',
          'Red',
          'Crimson',
          'Azure',
          'Ivory',
          'Red',
          'Red',
          'Khaki',
          'Hot pink']}
{'data': [{'count': 1, 'name': 'Coral'},
          {'count': 2, 'name': 'Ivory'},
          {'count': 3, 'name': 'Red'},
          {'count': 1, 'name': 'Crimson'},
          {'count': 1, 'name': 'Azure'},
          {'count': 1, 'name': 'Khaki'},
          {'count': 1, 'name': 'Hot pink'}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) form the collections library to count the values.

You can try something like this:

```py
from collections import Counter

data = get_data_from_endpoint(request)[data]
c = Counter(data)
result = {'data': [{'name': element, 'count': c[element]} for element in c]}
```